# Use Guzzle to HTTP GET to external API with Symfony

Tags: php, http, symfony, guzzle

I am new to Symfony development so excuse me if this is a dumb question. I am trying to GET JSON data from an external API. I have tried to run a GET request via Postman and got the correct data in JSON format back so I know my URL is correct.

I have the following code written to use Guzzle to HTTP GET a set of JSON data from my external API:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ScheduleController {

/**
 * @Route("/schedule")
 */

public function getJobs() {
    // Create a client with a base URI
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://my.api.url/']);
    // Send a request to http://my.api.url/site/67/module/1449/item
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'site/67/module/1449/item');
    dump($response);
}
}
```

I am trying to follow along as closely as I can with [the Guzzle quick start guide.](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) I am getting a 500 error from this code:
`Attempted to load class "Client" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller\GuzzleHttp".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client", "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client" or "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client"?`

I have a use statement for `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line:
`$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://my.api.url/']);`

Should be:

`$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://my.api.url/']);`

or:

`$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://my.api.url/']);`

Either one would work since you imported the namespace. You probably want the first option. When you put GuzzleHttp\Client PHP thinks it's a relative namespace that's why it's saying "AppBundle\Controller\GuzzleHttp\Client" cannot be found.

Comment: I got this error from that change (I am using the first line of code you suggested): `Attempted to load class "Client" from namespace "GuzzleHttp".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client", "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client" or "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client"?`

Comment: Have you actually installed guzzle through composer? Based on that error it seems guzzle is not installed.

Comment: I did install it. Is there a way to troubleshoot installation?

Comment: You could run 'composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle' from the command line root of your project.

Comment: You can always just look under vendor but based on the error message I suspect you have another file with new Guzzle\Client in it.  Or maybe another method withing the same file.  Maybe you are editing the wrong file.  Do a global search.

Answer (score 1):

I set the IP address from `localhost:8087` to my windows IP address `192.168.x.x:8087`.

It worked so there was no need to do anything with linux ports/docker ports etc.